# Is it an antipattern to resolve a Promise with no argument just to control the flow of an app?

Tags: javascript

If I had two independent functions that are usually called separately like below:

```
   function one() {
        axios.post('XXXX', {
           foo: foo,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            //do something;
        });
    }

   function two() {
       axios.post('YYYY', {
          foo: foo,
       })
       .then((response) => {
           //do something;
       });
   }
```

but somewhere in my code, I had another function that called both of these but the execution was important in where I need `two()` to run and finish executing before `one()` does, I realize this below is unreliable.

```
function all() {
     two();
     one();   
}
```

I want to ensure the times where I call these functions together elsewhere, I get them in the correct order and that the first finishes executing before the second is called.
Can I have rewrite the function `two()` so it will return a Promise that just `resolves()` with no argument inside of it so that it will trigger `one()` like follows:

```
function two() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.post('YYYY', {
         foo: foo,
      })
      .then((response) => {
          //do something;
      })
      .then((response) => {
          resolve();
      });
    }      
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return axios.post(...)`? It's *already* a promise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe didn't think of that, thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*so that it will trigger one()*". That needs to be done in `all`, and has nothing to do with the implementation of `two`?

Comment: @Bergi by trigger, I mean ensure that `one()` only runs after `two()` is complete.  I wanted to use `resolve()` to signal that

Comment: @raulInsto Oh, sorry, now I get the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an anti-pattern, and is in fact a great use case for async/await:

```
async function all() {
     await two();
     await one();   
}
```

will ensure that two completes before one begins.

Answer (score -2):

> Can I rewrite the function `two()` so it will return a Promise

Yes, you can, and yes, you should! Returning a promise to signal when the work is done is a best practice and should totally be done by *every* asynchronous function - not just `two` but also `one` and `all`. Fulfilling the promises with `undefined` is fine when there's no useful result, although it would be more meaningful to return the response data and just ignore it at the call site when you don't need it.

> Can I call `resolve()`?

No, you should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Use promise chaining, where the promise result is the return value of the callback:

```
function one() {
    return axios.post('XXXX', {
//  ^^^^^^
       foo: foo,
    }).then(response => {
        // do something
        return undefined; // or something else
    });
}

// same for `two`

function all() {
    return two().then(one);
}
```

or with `async`/`await`:

```
async function one() {
    const response = await axios.post('YYYY', {
       foo: foo,
    })
    // do something
    return undefined; // or something else
}

// same for `two`

async function all() {
    await two();
    await one();   
}
```